# Using awk minus is not working although sum works fine?

Tags: awk

Any idea what I'm doing wrong with this statement, for minus I replaced += with -= ?
The idea is to sum or subtract matching rows. Sum works fine, minus will just a "-" sign before the value but not subtract.

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{ for (j in a) {s=j; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {s=s" "a[j][i]}; print s}}'

awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]-=$i}} END{ for (j in a) {s=j; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {s=s" "a[j][i]}; print s}}' 
input: 
test    100     100     100     100
test2    100     90     80      0
test2    10      10     10       20
test     5       5      0       0

sum:
test2 110 100 90 20
test 105 105 100 100
minus:
test2 -110 -100 -90 -20
test -105 -105 -100 -100
```

Comment: What is the problem? For, for example, `test2` and `$2`: -100-10=-110. What did you expect to get?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. The code you present works as expected. When you create an array element using the statement `a[$1][i]` it gets the initial numeric value of `0`. So when you write `a[$1][i]-=$i`, and you encounter `test` in `$1` for the first time you have `a[test][2]-=100` which equals `a[test][2] = a[test][2] - 100` but since it is initially `0`, you have `a[test][2] = 0 - 100`

Comment: In short: with `sum` the first value is added to the implicit zero, with `minus` the first value is subtracted from the implicit zero. In the latter case you are probably expecting the first value to be treated differently, but haven't coded that difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no expected output, here is a guess at it:

```
$ awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        a[$1][i]=((a[$1][i]==""||i==1)?$i:a[$1][i]-$i) 
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        for(j=1;j<=NF;j++)
            printf "%s%s",a[i][j],(j==NF?ORS:OFS)
}' file
```

Output:

```
test2 90 80 70 -20
test 95 95 100 100
```

It's for GNU awk since I'm using two-dimensional arrays.